# HTML whitespace after period

Tags: html, smtp

Simple case here. Consider the following HTML:

```
<p>
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
</p>
```

Which outputs:

```
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
```

Notice a whitespace was added when removing the break. How do I get ride of it?

My HTML is being sent by SMTP so I don't control how those "breaks" reach the server. I do my necessary breaks with `<br>`. All rest must be ignored, which is happening, except if the line ends with period (`.`).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can format source code with the [Code Sample `{}`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VYd26.png) toolbar button—I've done it for you this time.

Comment: I've noticed. I was looking for it as soon as I saw the end result :). Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you mean that you want `text.This` together between third and fourth sentences? (BTW, if you encode mail properly you definitively do control how those line ends reach the server.)

Comment: No, just between the two lines. You're right, the answer was in the C library. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I still can't understand what's wrong with your current rendering. And, as about mail, if you encode stuff properly not a single byte will be lost—just think that you can even attach pictures!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, content of HTML's element (with exceptions like `<pre>`) are formatted and line breaks are replaced by space.

You could consider sending each of your lines in a separate `<span>` that way they will be appended without space.

PS: I am not sure what your 'necessary breaks' are and what's the limitation linked to SMTP here. What forbids you from sending all the lines directly appended without line break ?

Comment: I don't see how the `<span>` does the trick. About SMTP, I'm using a C library that sends the data. It will probably break the lines automatically when sending my html message, so I don't control where they occur. By 'necessary breaks', I mean where I want the text to actually break. Thank you for the info.

Comment: I said `span` as it's default inline, but the solution is more about wrapping the lines each in a dom element, and using some CSS to get rid of the whitespace that you cannot remove within a `p`.
https://plnkr.co/edit/pCsit0UTWVN5dvGVcRSJ

Comment: Reading what you say about your library that breaks line automatically: wrapping your lines in DOM elements and using some CSS - if you can - to ensure the behavior you want could be a solution as it does not rely on content's `\n\r`.

Answer (score 0):

My particular problem was in the C library I was using. It was automatically breaking lines at punctuation, up to a maximum of 76 chars, although the limit for SMTP is 1000 (including CRLF). When sending something like:

`<p> Something long and over 76 characters.Something else who increases the total size of the line.</p>`

It would break it into 2 lines:

`<p> Something long and over 76 characters.
Something else who increases the total size of the line.</p>`

Decided not to break it at period (.) and solved the issue, at least for my scenario. (I was sending an email address and it would always break there)

This is not an answer for whom might have a problem with line breaking in HTML!

Thank you to [ATX](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1656893/atx) for its contribution.